# How to set different Selectors (color) to specific rows in a gridview on Android

Tags: android, gridview, colors, selector

I have a gridview of icons with the size of 5x6, total 30 itens. Each one of the rows (there are 6 rows) must have a different selector colour (selector is that colour that appears when an item is pressed). I need to change the select colour of the items no the background.

Can u help me with that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HedUg.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, inside getView() method (or onBindViewHolder()),
you can set the background color for a specific row based on current item position (you can use a switch case),

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: The backgound color is not the same as the selector. and btw how do I do this in a switch case?